# Composer freezes while installing Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am installing Laravel 5.6 with the composer. This process is carried out in Windows 10's native command prompt. However when I type in `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel my_blog`, composer doesn't do anything. It just stays still. Left it for 1.5 hours and the result is same.

Please help me fix it.

Comment: you are using windows or linux?\

Comment: type `composer` and check whether its load

Comment: I am using Windows 10 and yes typing `composer` it loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 php composer create-project laravel/laravel my_blog --prefer-dist
```

File `composer.phar`  must be in folder where you start command `create-project` OR add `composer.phar` to your PATH environment variable

For test (in terminal):

```
composer -V
```

Comment: Not worked. Says `Could not open input file: composer`!

Comment: @sanjay `php composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel my_blog --prefer-dist`

Comment: A little mistake. OK! Let me try it.

Comment: No errors at all. It just freezes. Nothing happens. I tried uninstalling and re-installing composer. Still not working.

Comment: Same with composer.phar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165487/discussion-between-ilya-yaremchuk-and-sanjay).